# Firebase in react's componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm making a Firebase + ReactJS app, and I need to check if an element exists before the components mount, and set the state's `existing` property based on that.

The problem is to do that I need to use

```
componentWillMount() {
        let newState = {}
        firebase.database()
            .ref(`/refs/${this.props.match.params.channel}`)
            .once('value', val => val.val())
            .then(value => {
                let val = value.val()
                if (val) {
                    let dbRef = val.ref
                    newState = {
                        dbRef,
                        exists: true
                    }
                } else {
                    newState.exists = false
                }
                this.setState(newState)
            })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
            if(this.state.exists) {
                console.log(`/channels/${this.state.dbRef}/messages`)
                firebase.database()
                    .ref(`/channels/${this.state.dbRef}/messages`)
                    .on('value', snap => {
                        const snapshot = snap.val()
                        let messages = []
                        if (snapshot) {
                            Object.keys(snapshot).forEach(k => messages.push(snapshot[k]))
                        }
                        this.setState({ messages })
                        this.refs.messages.scrollTop = this.refs.messages.scrollHeight
                    })
    }
}
```

which is async, so by the time I need to access the property in `componentDidMount` the firebase query might not have been resolved yet. Any ideas on how I could fix it? Is it even possible to use `await` in a component's functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you mount the component after the query resolves? Where are you trying to do this before navigating a new route? a little bit more code and explanation would be helpful to suggest better solutions

Comment: How do I tell React to mount a component after the query? The component is just going to sit there,  so that's really everything I'm trying to do...

Comment: You can conditionally render a component. If you add a snippet from your code it would be more easy to suggest something. you can check if a state or prop value to render the component or not.